# Mac 10.7 - Cannot use make utility after installing xcode

Tags: macos, mac, perl, make

I'm trying to install a perl module that I manually downloaded from CPAN, but am encountering difficulties.

```
$perl Makefile.PL 
Welcome to JSON (v.2.53)
=============================
If you install JSON::XS v.2.27, it makes JSON faster.

 ************************** CAUTION **************************
 * This is 'JSON version 2' and there are many differences   *
 * to version 1.xx                                           *
 * Please check your applications useing old version.        *
 *   See to 'INCOMPATIBLE CHANGES TO OLD VERSION' and 'TIPS' *
 *************************************************************


Writing Makefile for JSON
$make
make: *** No rule to make target `/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/config.h', needed by `Makefile'.  Stop.
```

Here's someone with the same problem, but I couldn't get his solution to work for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793499/perl-config-h-needed-by-makefile-problem-after-osx-lion-upgrade

I have Xcode installed - and the Command Line Tools package. Entering 'which make' outputs:

```
$which make
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
```

Which perl outputs:

```
$which perl
/usr/bin/perl
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Is this an issue with Perl?

Comment: Works no problem for me on 10.8 with developer tools installed. Note the problem is not with make—it is executing successfully, but there is a problem with the generated Makefile. Could you try upgrading Xcode and/or Mac OS X?

Comment: @andrew.n Upgrading Xcode might not be feasible for me - I'm using a company machine and they control which versions of software we get. My Xcode is Version 4.4, though I see 4.5 is out. Perhaps it has something to do with the perl file it claims to depend on? Then again, I followed the steps of another person having the same problem to no avail.